# Caching the entire table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, ehcache

We have a spring boot web service(with spring data, hibernate) which generates a huge file by reading an entire table from the database and returns it. It takes a lot of time to do this which is way more than the time out set by the client. So I have decided to use ehcache to cache the entire table's data and generate the file from it(I know cache is not designed for this, but I dont have any other idea). It performs satisfactorily. But the problem comes when we need to do updates on the data. The updates comes at a per record level, but the cache is stored at the whole table level. I am not sure how to make ehcache look into the records within the cached object and modify them(I dont want to store every row as a separate cache object due to some performance reasons). Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Right now, to manage this I got rid of ehcache and using a hash map. This led to a lot of boiler plate code which I dont like.

EDIT: Is there a way to hook on to ehcache eviction mechanism and manually alter the cache object?

Comment: How have you applied caching, are you using Spring Cache or have you used the 2nd level cache option of hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Using the parameter timeToLiveSeconds into ehcache.xml you can specify hoy much time would the data be in cache. One option is to provide a time (for example, 24 hours), so data will be in cache for this time, and on next method call will be refreshed.

To avoid the client to do this call (because of the time spent), you can make an Spring scheduled task to call this with the same period, so the cache will be refreshed periodically.

Other way is forcing the cache to refresh when you make changes calling an especific function. So you can remove the cache, and then call the method again to re-charge data in cache. In this link is told how to remove a cache in order to force refresh: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/55466-how-to-force-ehcache-to-refresh

Comment: I think I was not clear about the time part. I cannot afford to reload the entire data every 5 mins or so. The file needs to be generated every five minutes and the data needs to be upto date.

Comment: I think I do not understand well your problem. As I said, the cache will only be reloaded after the time you specify (f.d. 24 hours), or manually when you update data. Obviously if data is updated in database every 5 minutos, it won't be a valid solution anymore